# Saving DrawingState in WorldWind with OpenGL4

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, opengl-4, worldwind

I am currently trying to display a PointCloud on the WorldWind map. All the examples on the WorldWind website are done using OpenGL2. But i tried to use OpenGL4 instead, because I used it a little bit before.

Now I ran into a problem while managing drawing state:

> "*Any state that we change from the WorldWind default must be restored
> after rendering the cube, or it will cause other objects to render
> incorrectly*"

[Managing drawing state](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/tutorials/build-a-custom-renderable). In OpenGL2 it is fairly simple. Before anything is drawn `beginDrawing()` is called.

```
protected void beginDrawing(DrawContext dc){

GL2 gl = dc.getGL().getGL2();

int attrMask = GL2.GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
gl.glPushAttrib(attrMask);

if (!dc.isPickingMode())
    dc.beginStandardLighting(); }
```

The `glPushAttrib` method is used to save the state and is later poped in the `endDrawing()`.

```
protected void endDrawing(DrawContext dc){
GL2 gl = dc.getGL().getGL2();

if (!dc.isPickingMode())
    dc.endStandardLighting();

gl.glPopAttrib();   }
```

Can I achieve the same thing with OpenGL4? If yes how?

Everything I found until now is for OpenGL2. I found out that `DrawContext` has Methods called `restoreDefaultCurrentColor()`, `restoreDefaultDepthTesting()` and `restoreDefaultBlending()` but they didn't help.

Edit: So i found out that if i call `gl.glBindProgram(0)` to unbind the currently used program i actually can see something. I see the standard layers of WorldWind. That means the stars, city names etc. But the Globe is still dark. It looks like something breaks during the rendering.

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea because the fixed pipeline and the programmable pipeline are very different and Worldwind uses the fixed pipeline as far as I remember. Moreover, if you use GL4, you'll have to manage the matrices and the transforms by yourself, it's not trivial. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gouessej Hey thanks for the answer :) As is said i am currently trying to display quite big PointClouds in WorldWind and thought that, in theory, it would be more efficient to use GL4.

Comment: Well, you need to track everything you change, and restore it. You can get a bit further with `GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS` for `glPushAttribs`/`glPopAttribs`, but there is still stuff which you can do which won't be restored by that.

Comment: @derhass Thanks for the suggestion but it doesnt seem to change anything. I wonder if it is even possible to do what i want to do. Currently it looks to me like the programmable Pipeline somehow breaks the fixed Pipeline which is being used for the globe(i think).

Comment: "it looks to me like the programmable Pipeline somehow breaks the fixed Pipeline which is being used for the globe(i think)", well if yoiu restore program 0, then the drawing will be back to the fixed pipeline. But there are still many states which you might have modified.

Comment: @derhass hmm ok. I already tried quite a lot of different things but nothing seems to work and im by no means an expert with OpenGL. But would you say that in theory it should be possible?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what exactly you want to do. But restoring GL state should be possible. Just have a look at all the different GL funbctions you are calling - almost all of them modify some state, and there is a way to query the prior state. Not going to say that it is necessarily efficient, but you can definitively restore the state to how it is supposed to be for the default renderer.

Comment: @derhass For now my goal is to simply display a cube somewhere on the Globe with the programmable pipeline.Later i want to display PointClouds. Currently im not really using much. I simply draw the cube using `glDrawArrays` and in my vertexShader i color it. Thats about it.

Comment: well, to be able to draw a cube with shaders and vertex arrays/VBOs, you have to set up lots of GL state. It is hard to tell which state you screwed up so that the rest doesn't render the way it is supposed to, but you defintively did change something.

Comment: @derhass hmm yes. But shouldnt `GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS` with `glPushAttribs` save all states?

Comment: @FieryToken use the fixed pipeline to draw your stuff, it's better than nothing.

Comment: @gouessej yeah i think i will do that. I've spent a lot of hours now and couldnt get it to work. I started 3 weeks ago with OpenGL and i think right now im wasting a lot of time trying to get it to work. So i guess i will just use the fixed pipeline for now. I thank you and derhass for the help :)